# why std::less<int>() is a function object

Tags: c++, stl

why is `std::less<int>()` a function object as used in

```
std::sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(),std::less<int>());
```

but `std::less<int>` is a type and operator is function call, there is no object been created, or memory address we can reference

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses

Comment: [Operator overloading](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/less/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::less<int>()` is a constructor call. It creates a new `std::less<int>` object which, yes, has overloaded `operator()`.

Comment: Nitpick: `T()` is *value-initialization* of a temporary of type `T`. It does create an object, but the behavior might be different than that of the default constructor.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Value-initialization may omit the call to the default constructor? Oh for the...

Comment: On the contrary, value initialization offers stricter guarantees. For example the default ctor of a POD is a noop, but value initialization guarantees all members will be set to zero.

Answer (score 3):

`std::less<int>()` does actually create a temporary instance of `std::less` that has a memory address (even though it is empty and therefore won't occupy any real memory with any sane compiler).   `sort` keeps this instance around and uses its overloaded `operator ()` to perform comparisons.

`std::less<int>()(a, b)` would directly perform a comparison between two integers in case the use of both object creation syntax and operator() calls is what confused you.

Comment: Nitpick: all objects do occupy some space, it is up to the compiler to decide how much, but it must occupy at least 1 byte in any *conforming*, *sane* or not, compiler.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Strictly speaking, the compiler could allocate no memory for the object, but only if such an action can be detected with the use of UB.